# Converting ArcGIS topology rules file (*.rul) to *.txt, *.csv or *.xls for reviewing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, topology, excel

Has anyone converted ESRI's topology rules file (.rul) into another format?

I built a complex topology rules set and would like to QC it in something easier to read and work with than ArcCatalog.

A text file and spreadsheet format would work great.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Richie Carmichael's (from ESRI Prototype Labs) Excellent **ArcGIS Diagrammer**

ArcGIS 9.2/9.3

It's a **visual editor** of 
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/body.cfm?tocVisable=1&ID=2016&TopicName=Geodatabase%20XML

Most up-to-date version (have been multiple ones)
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=F12ADF8F-1422-2418-34B2-C276C6BCCF98

As XML based you should have no issues editing in [Notepad ++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (supports xml) or Excel 2007 and above.

For ArcGIS 10

http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2010/07/arcgis-diagrammer-for-arcgis-10.html