# GeoDatabase topology and rules with a *.rul file

Tags: arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, topology

I have been working for some time on a solution to a problem much [like this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69427/how-to-identify-overlapping-corners-in-plss-sections).
I have several layers that I want to resolve together.  I have them all in topology (geodatabase) and have been trying to decide which [rules](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/01mm/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf) and in what order would be best practice or even would accomplish.
For instance the same data in the overlapping sections needs to not overlap or have gaps.
That data should not move where a county polygon is near and should be moved to it.
As should the school districts.
All data layers are polygonal.
Ending with all features being moved and made exact (within tolerance) to the plss layer which is first repaired for gaps and slivers.  The topology tool allows you to load a *.rul file, which I assume is an ordered XML.  I haven't found one anywhere to examine it.
To my question does anyone hold a *.rul file that would begin to give me insight into the rules and the order (the tolerances I will most likely have to tweak for my data)?

If [user823](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/arcgis-topology-rules-file-rul) would ever come back by I might convince him to post his complex rule set.